# Squarring the Euler's formula

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

$$\begin{align}&e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0 &\text{ (Euler's Formula)}\\
\implies &e^{\pi i} = -1&\\
\implies &e^{2\pi i} = 1& \text{ (Squaring both sides)}\\
\implies &e^{2\pi i} = e^0 (e^0 = 1)&\\
\implies &2\pi i = 0&\end{align}$$

how is this possible?

Comment: The function $e^z$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$. So from $e^a=e^b$ you can only conclude that $a=b + 2\pi i  k$ for some integral $k$.

Answer (score 3):

In the complex setting,

$$e^{z_1}=e^{z_2}\implies z_1=z_2$$ is a false conclusion because the function $$z\mapsto e^z$$ is **not injective**. In fact, for every $z\in \mathbb C$ and every $k\in\mathbb Z$, you have

$$e^{z+2k\pi\cdot  i} = e^z$$

and,  if $k\neq 0$, then $z\neq z+2k\pi\cdot i$.